# How can I turn these jQuery mouse events to touch events (for iPad)

Tags: jquery, ipad, events, touch, mouse

I have created a jQuery scratch ticket that works in a way that the user can left-click+hold  and move the cursor to scratch the top image off to see the image underneath. This works fine with mouse events. I want to be able to  use on an iPad as well (touch events). How do I modify it?

```
var topImage = new Image();
var bottomImage = new Image();
var coinImage = new Image();
bottomImage.src = "images/question.png";
coinImage.src = "images/coin.png";  

function init()
{
var isMouseDown = false;
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
$('body').append('<canvas id="overlay" width="'+canvasWidth+'" height="'+canvasHeight+'" />'); // Create the coin overlay canvas
var overlayctx = $('canvas')[1].getContext('2d');
overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, 0,0);


function scratchOff(x, y)
{
    mainctx.save();
    mainctx.beginPath();
    mainctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false); // we don't fill or stroke the arc intentionally
    mainctx.clip();
    mainctx.drawImage(bottomImage, 0, 0);
    mainctx.restore();
}

$('#overlay').mousedown(function(e){
        isMouseDown = true;
        var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var relY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        scratchOff(relX, relY, true);
});
$('#overlay').mousemove(function(e){
    var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var relY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    overlayctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, relX-radius, relY-radius);
    if (isMouseDown) scratchOff(relX, relY, false);
});
$('#overlay').mouseup(function(e){
    isMouseDown = false;
});

var mainctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var radius = 20;
topImage.onload = function(){
    mainctx.drawImage(topImage, 0, 0);
};
topImage.src = "images/skava.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following event names:

mousedown -> touchstart

mouseup -> touchend

for 'wipe' (left to right or right to left) gestures i'd recommend using:
http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

hope that helps

Comment: I have tried this and I also changed "mousemove" to "touchmove", but still didn't work for me.